# Difference in how Python's == and > operators compare values of differing data types

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python,
`print(1 == '1')` returns False but
`print(1 > '1')` raises a TypeError.
Why?

Answer (score 3):

#### Equality always has a sensible definition

Conceptually, `==` checks if two objects are the same. This notion is perfectly well-defined for objects of different types.

- Is the number 1 the same thing as the word "gold"? Clearly not.
- Is my cat the same thing as the empty set? Clearly not.

The answers to these questions are not "I don't know" but "no". So the operator `==` should return `False`, not raise an exception, on objects of different types.

#### Ordering does not always have a sensible definition

Now consider `>`. Conceptually, this checks if one object is "greater than", or "after", another. But there are clearly some pairs of types for which this isn't well-defined.

- Is `2+3i` greater than, or after, `3+2i`?
- Is my cat greater than, or after, your cat?
- Is the number one greater than, or after, the word "gold"?

None of these questions have sensible answers. So `>` doesn't have a sensible definition on imaginary numbers, or cats, or between numbers and strings, and should raise an exception.

#### A note on coercion

We might think `1 > "1"` has a natural definition by converting ("coercing") `"1"` to an integer. But combined with the order on strings (which does have a definition: "gold" is before "silver" in the dictionary), this leads to losing transitivity: `3` is greater than `2` and `"2"` is alphabetically after `"12"`, but `3` is not greater than `12`.

Comment: Great answer!!!

Comment: @enzo Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I was looking into the document, it says:

> The <, <=, > and >= operators are only defined where they make sense; for example, they raise a **TypeError** exception when one of the arguments is a complex number.

So, if you do:

```
1 > '1'
```

you will get a **TypeError**

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

It is something like :

```
1 > 'a'
```

**You are comparing an integer to string.**

---

---

Coming back to

```
1 == '1'
```

> **The == operator is always defined** but for some object types (for example, class objects) is equivalent to `is`.

**Link to document: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons**

*I think By the nature of `==` it will always gives a Boolean (True/False) value*.